# Derived class in UC gives "type exist in both dlls" error

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, user-controls

User Control has a class ImButtonLink derived from Image button.

```
protected void reserv_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect(((ImButtonLink)sender).GetURL);
}
```

In Click Action function I get following error:

> The type 'ImButtonLink' exists in both 'App_Web_carstable.ascx.6bb32623.yi5kff3g.dll' and 'App_Web_carstable.ascx.6bb32623.urge3_if.dll'

Any ideas? My derived class has only string parameter in addition to ImageButton class for storing navigation link. Maybe there's another way to store link in ImageButton?

Comment: You should delete the temporary visual studio files

Comment: you may be giving more than one definitions of a single class. May be like One defined in your project and another is coming from any other external DLL.

Comment: it's a UC without any dll and it's define only once. I get this error on a Sharepoint server where I use it, so it's not about VS temp files I suppose...

When I try (ImageButton)sender it works just fine.

Comment: did you define the class in a seperate namespace? Because else it probably collides with a type in another namespace. Also, the generated files are not Visual Studio temp files, but ASP.NET temp files, found on the server in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\<framework_version>\Temporary ASP.NET Files\<web application name> (not sure if that's also true for SharePoint, but since it's just an ASP.NET application, it's probably the same)

Comment: I dont have any namespace declaration in UC at all (it has ascx and ascx.cs files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the control is `CodeFile` (and not `Codebehind`) mode, or included in a `CodeFile` page. You may transform it to CodeBehind and rebuild your solution.

If you want to keep it CodeFile, you may set `batch="false"` in the compilation element of your web.config like this :

```
<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" batch="false" ...>
```

Be aware that there are performance issues when a page is first accessed.
And don't forget to delete your temporary asp.net files (you may need to stop your web server)

You may also have a look at this, very interesting solution though I never had the opportunity to test it by now :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15253750/1236044